# static constexpr template member gives undefined-reference when specialized

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, constexpr

The following code gives an undefined reference linking error:

```
template<int>
struct X {
    static constexpr int x = 0;
};

template<>
constexpr int X<1>::x;

int main() 
{   
    return X<1>::x;
}
```

But I don't know exactly why.

Is it possible to define a data-member without to specialize the whole template?

To be clear: this code compiles fine, but gives a linker error (undefined-reference).

Comment: Perhaps your "And" question should be the leading one.

Comment: Yes, edited ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to define a data-member without [specializing] the whole template?

`static` data members of a class template *are* allowed to be explicitly specialized ([temp.expl.spec]), however if you wish to do this, you cannot already specify an initializer for the member within the class template (class.static.data). That is,

if we replace `constexpr` with `const`, this code would be fine:

```
template<int>
struct X {
    static const int x;
};

template<int I>
const int X<I>::x = 0;

template<>
const int X<1>::x = 1;
```

But this code would *NOT* be fine:

```
template<int>
struct X {
    static const int x = 0;
};

template<>
const int X<1>::x = 1;
```

You can see the difference is where we initialize the variable for the primary template.

Now, if we wish to replace `const` with `constexpr`, then we're **required** to provide an initializer (class.static.data):

> A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the
>   class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*
>   in which every *initializer-clause* that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression

So we end up in this weird situation where we can specialize the `static` member, but not if it is `constexpr` because `constexpr` requires an initializer. IMHO this is a shortcoming of the standard.

However, it doesn't appear that all modern compilers agree.

gcc 8.0.0 compiles (but doesn't link) your code as-is (wrong), however if you add an initializer for the specialization it complains about duplicate initialization (right).

clang 6.0.0 doesn't compile the code as-is (right), but when you add the initializer it works without a hitch (wrong, but this is probably what the standard should dictate)

MSVC 19.00.23506 doesn't compile the code as-is (right), AND it doesn't compile the code when you add the initializer (complaining about redefinition) (right).

In the end, it might just be easier to push the specialization into a helper Traits class:

```
template<int>
struct X_Traits{
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template<>
struct X_Traits<1>{
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

template<int I>
struct X {
    static constexpr int x=X_Traits<I>::value;
    // ...
};
```

---

In C++17 and beyond we can make use of [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) to avoid needing to specialize our traits class:

```
template<int I>
struct X_Traits{
    static constexpr int get_value(){
        if constexpr(I==1){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
};

template<int I>
struct X {
    static constexpr int x=X_Traits<I>::get_value();
    // ...
};

int main(){
    static_assert(X<0>::x == 0);
    static_assert(X<1>::x == 1);
}
```

Comment: But this does not explain, why the above code compiles fine, but gives a linker error.

Comment: @wimalopaan: the above code appears to compile in gcc (a bug), but not clang or msvc. What I was trying to say was that the code was ill-formed because it attempts to redefine an existing `static constexpr` member ("cannot specialize a single member of a templated class")

Comment: But the excerpt that StoryTeller gives us from the C++Standard explicitly mentions the specialization. So a specialization of a single member must be possible? Or am I reading the above quote of the standard wrong?

Comment: @wimalopaan: You're reading it correctly I think. I think my wording needs some work. You can provide full explicit specialization for just about anything.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just looked a bit deeped into http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization and now I got it.

Answer (score 4):

You stumbled upon a "small" issue due to explicitly specializing. If we refer to [[temp.expl.spec]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#13):

> An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template or an
>   explicit specialization of a static data member template is a
>   definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it
>   is a declaration. [ Note: The definition of a static data member of a
>   template that requires default-initialization must use a
>   braced-init-list:
>
> ```
> template<> X Q<int>::x;                         // declaration
> template<> X Q<int>::x ();                      // error: declares a function
> template<> X Q<int>::x { };                     // definition
> ```
>
> — end note ]

Meaning that you *declare* `X<1>::x` to exist, but not define it. Hence it's undefined.

What I find crazy, is that your compiler just accepts it. You can't declare `constexpr` variables without defining them, in general. This is quite odd.

Comment: What's weirder is if you do provide a value for the "specialization" Clang magically accepts it, while gcc and MSVC do not. I would have thought that this was a redefinition issue from the start, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: @AndyG - That's disappointing. Those are indeed two opposing forces (the specialization being a declaration, and the `constexpr` requiring an initializer), but it shouldn't be *that* hard to reconcile.

Comment: Looks like a language defect?

Comment: @wimalopaan - I'm not sure it's a language defect. The rules aren't really mutually exclusive. I think it's a quality of implementation issue. This is an attempt to declare but not initialize a `constexpr` variable. So there should be a diagnostic. And if you do initialize it, it's a definition, so the program shuold be well-formed. End of story.

Comment: Well if I try to initialize it in the specialization I get a duplicate initialization error!

Comment: @wimalopaan - I feel for you. But you should file a bug report over it. And use Andy's workaround (which it's a shame he deleted).

Comment: @StoryTeller: A peek at class.static.data slightly muddies things more. In C++11 a `static constexpr` member must still be defined in namespace scope but without initialization, which OP is missing. This became deprecated in C++17.

Comment: @AndyG - Well, the deprecation is due to `static constexpr` members becoming implicitly `inline` in C++17.

Answer (score 2):

like this.

```
template<int i>
struct X {
    static constexpr int x = i==0?2:10;
};

int main() 
{   
    return X<1>::x;
}
```

notice that you do not need to define it outside of class.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I want to know the root-cause of the above error.

Comment: Great use of a constant expression to initialize the member! It might get a little convoluted if one wants to specialize for more than one value, but I like the simplicity of this.